# Transform translate ruins rotation axis

Tags: html, css

When I use `translateX` it changes the `transform-origin` rotation axis from `top center` to `top right`.

All containers are exactly the size of the children.

[image]

```
#arrow {
    position: absolute;

    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;

    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```
<div id="depth">

   <img id="sensorImg" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/282502094202732544/1000456309793116170/Depth_Flattened.svg" alt="depth"></img>    
  
   <img id="arrow" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/282502094202732544/1000670507890389062/Polygon.png"></img> 
                
</div>
```

Comment: translate then rotate

Comment: I already did this; it changes the final position of the needle (not at the center where I need it to be)

Comment: the sensorImg image is not a square one so we don't have a perfect circle inside

Comment: seems to be a positioning issue, the arrow is not aligning with the image, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6rzg1oe3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translate then rotate and make sure you have a square image. The one you are using is not square so you can make the container square using `aspect-ratio`

```css
#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  animation: a 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes a{
  to{transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(360deg)}
}

#depth {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border:1px solid red;
}
img {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="depth">

  <img id="sensorImg" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/282502094202732544/1000456309793116170/Depth_Flattened.svg" alt="depth">

  <img id="arrow" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/282502094202732544/1000670507890389062/Polygon.png">

</div>
```